# Showing an empty as first option in select tag

Tags: angularjs

My app is showing an empty select field as first entry. I have read the other solution given and tried it but still its not working.

My controller code is:

```
.controller('userCreateController', function(User,Profile,Auth) {
      alert("hello");
      var vm = this;
      vm.type = 'create';
     Profile.all() //this service fetch all profiles to be shown in select field
     .success(function(data){
      vm.profile = data;

});
vm.userData.profile = vm.profile[0]; //here i have set default value for select field
```

And my  html page is:

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Profile</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <select ng-model="user.userData.profile" ng-options="person._id  as person.profileName for person in user.profile">
  </select>
</div>
```

Hierarchy of vm.profile

```
{
  "_id": 46,
  "profile": ObjectId("5516498e95b84548156db754"),
  "isActive": true,
  "password": "$2a$10$h8WTqsbNzTA5EqUcPUllYOCSjt0YDCBULEvDcntkg/muEHpAwX/xO",
  "username": "admin",
  "name": "admin",
  "reciptBook": [],
  "__v": 0
}, {
  "_id": 48,
  "profile": ObjectId("55168b8fbf769e6407ae3603"),
  "isActive": false,
  "password": "$2a$10$DnE84kyL9LI8tE3Fxet5su2ysjzRwnDXeriWOui3iDAki6eb53qn.",
  "username": "hello",
  "name": "hello",
  "reciptBook": [],
  "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: can you provide us data hierarchy of  vm.profile :)

Comment: /* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 46,
    "profile" : ObjectId("5516498e95b84548156db754"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "password" : "$2a$10$h8WTqsbNzTA5EqUcPUllYOCSjt0YDCBULEvDcntkg/muEHpAwX/xO",
    "username" : "admin",
    "name" : "admin",
    "reciptBook" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 48,
    "profile" : ObjectId("55168b8fbf769e6407ae3603"),
    "isActive" : false,
    "password" : "$2a$10$DnE84kyL9LI8tE3Fxet5su2ysjzRwnDXeriWOui3iDAki6eb53qn.",
    "username" : "hello",
    "name" : "hello",
    "reciptBook" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: don't dump blobs of code into comments, update the question where you can format the code and make it readable

Comment: Also appears that you are setting `vm.userData.profile` before `vm.profile` data has been returned

Comment: in comments formatting is not an option actually @charlietfl

Comment: that's exactly why you should update the question itself

Comment: i set vm.userData.profile after assigning vm.profile =data also but still giving error

Comment: Errors should also be noted in question. What are they? `Profile.all()` is asynchronous so you have to set `vm.userdata.profile` in success callback

Comment: i have set there also but still empty option is shown

Comment: @BhawnaMalhotra Ping check my answer hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add empty option, that will have an undefined value.

```
<select ng-model="user.userData.profile" ng-options="person._id  as person.profileName for person in user.profile">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `vm.userData.profile = vm.profile[0]._id;` because in your model you are setting person._id in you select.

**UPDATE**:-

I added the minimum possble required plunker for you please check.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dRQnpDgNCv8mzKbdiKdR?p=preview)

Comment: this is also not working plus my profile field is a reference to other schema